# Linux : double-quote variables and for file loop

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

In another question, I was advised to ["double-quote $variables"](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes#When_Should_You_Quote.3F) in my script to avoid errors.

After reading a lot of info about double-quotes, I presume I can/must exclude wildcards from double-quote when I need (for example) to loop over files but I'd like to be sure.

Could you please tell me if both usage below are **correct** use of double-quotes?

```
for file in "$workingdir"/*; do
  #do something with $file
done

if [[ $workingdir == $variable* ]]; then
  #do something
fi
```

For what I've seen in my tests, using `"$workingdir/*"` will set the variable `file` with `$workingdir/*` which is not what I want.

Thank you.

Regards

Comment: Have any examples of what should happen vs what actually happens, for given files?

Comment: Actually, what happens is what I want: I've no problem with the code.
I'd like to be sure this is the correct way to do it as I'm still not very familiar with the use of double-quotes around variables.

Comment: Well, try using a variable (filename here?) that has spaces and newlines, and then see what happens, quoting usually avoids those kinds of problems. Might want to quote inside the [[/test too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example you gave is correct (assuming it means the obvious thing):

```
for file in "$workingdir"/*; do
```

This iterates over a list of the files in the directory corresponding to the value of the variable `workingdir`, and works even if that contains spaces or other funny characters.

However, the second example is more complicated:

```
if [[ $workingdir == $variable* ]]; then
```

In this case, the value of the variable `variable` will be treated as a pattern, not a fixed string. For example, if `variable` was set to "*foo", the overall condition will match if `$workingdir` contains "foo" anywhere in its value. If you wanted `$variable` to be treated as a literal string rather than a pattern, you'd again have to put it in double-quotes (but not the `*`, assuming you want *that* treated as a wildcard):

```
if [[ $workingdir == "$variable"* ]]; then
```

...and frankly, keeping track of where double-quoting variables matters and where it doesn't is more trouble than it's worth. (i.e. it's safe to leave them off on the left side of `=` or `==` inside `[[ ]]` -- but not the right side or in `[ ]`). So I just recommend double-quoting them everywhere so you don't have to keep such close track:

```
if [[ "$workingdir" == "$variable"* ]]; then
```

Answer (score 0):

[Filename expansion is done **after** word-splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions) (which is what double quotes are about...).

So `"$mydir"/*` expands to `"my directory"/*`after variable substitution, then to `my directory/*` (as a single word) after word-splitting, and then to `my directory/file1`, `my directory/file2` after filename expansion.